# If I redirect logs using rsyslog, will dmesg be affected?

Tags: kernel, logs, rsyslog

I am trying to get some logging in place and am trying to troubleshoot it and this question became relevant.

I use rsyslog config files to redirect some of my logging.  (Will use iptables logging since I am working with it but please assume the general case)

Under my rsyslog.d config I have

```
:msg, startswith, "iptables: " /var/log/iptables.log
:msg, startswith, "iptables denied: " /var/log/iptables.log
& ~
```

I would assume if this was working that it would no longer log to kern.log.

Since it is no longer going to kern.log does the redirect also effect the kernel ring buffer?

Comment: You may have to use `contains` and not `startswith` -- the kernel will likely append its own time stamp to iptables stuff before rsyslog sees it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` only applies to the preceeding selector, so you will need one for each of those `:msg` lines.

http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_conf_actions.html

Answer (score 2):

No, it only affects what you modified.